# how to click a button on popup using selenium::remote::driver in perl?

Tags: perl, selenium, xpath, popup, click

I want click on a button(xpath) in a popup in perl. i will switch in a popup with xpath.

my codeline:

```
my $popup->$driver->get_window_handles;;
$driver->switch_to_window($popup->[1]);
$driver->click();
```

i have write the script in perl and used Selenium::Remote::Driver and phantom.js

Comment: And what is your question? Does the code not do what you want? Are we talking a browser-popup (like an alert box), or an overlay, or a completely different browser window?

Answer (score 0):

```
=head2 accept_alert
 Description:
    Accepts the currently displayed alert dialog.  Usually, this is
    equivalent to clicking the 'OK' button in the dialog.
Example:
    $driver->accept_alert;
=cut

sub accept_alert {
    my ($self) = @_;
    my $res = { 'command' => 'acceptAlert' };
    return $self->_execute_command($res);
}
```

Comment: I pulled this out of the cucumber-remote-driver perl github repo. The skinny answer is  **$driver->accept_alert;**